# Problem with the following code

Tags: c

I want to the know the problems with the code presented below. I seem to be getting a segmentation fault.

```
void mallocfn(void *mem, int size)
{
    mem = malloc(size);
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr = NULL;
    mallocfn(ptr, sizeof(ptr));
    *ptr = 3;

    return;
}
```

Comment: @rohith Please just put the code here. Now it's still public but we have to follow a link.

Comment: Why can that code not be "publicized"?

Comment: @erisco Clearly a highly protected trade secret.

Comment: I don't get what the link is for. The code there has compilation errors.

Comment: @George. That is what I am asking for. I know there are compilation  errors. I want to know the reason behind them.

Comment: @rohith You say seg fault. Seg fault is a runtime error, not a compile time error.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your wrapper around malloc is misnamed in your example (you use `AllocateMemory` in the main(...) function) - so I'm taking it that the function you've called malloc is actually `AllocateMemory`, you're passing in a pointer *by value*, setting this parameter value to be the result of malloc, but when the function returns the pointer that was passed in will not have changed.

```
int *ptr = NULL;
AllocateMemory(ptr, sizeof(ptr));
*ptr = 3; // ptr is still NULL here.  AllocateMemory can't have changed it.
```

Comment: yeah, I misnamed the function.

Comment: How can I change the function so as to prevent seg fault.

Comment: @rohith Check out phoxis' answer - he/she provides a decent way to solve this.  Another option would be to change your mallocfn to _return_ the result of malloc (i.e. return the pointer).

Comment: phoxis's answer is incorrect, but could be made correct by changing the argument type from `void **` to `int **`.

Answer (score 3):

should be something like:

<strike>`void mallocfn(void **mem, int size)`</strike>

```
void mallocfn(int **mem, int size)
{
    *mem = malloc(size);
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr = NULL;
    mallocfn(&ptr, sizeof(ptr));
    *ptr = 3;

    return;
}
```

Because you need to edit the contents of `p` and not something *pointed b* `p`, so you need to send the pointer variable `p`'s address to the allocating function.

Also check @Will A 's answer

Comment: This code is incorrect. You cannot modify a `int *` through a pointer to `void *`. They are not the same type.

Comment: @George: That's irrelevant. The code is not assigning `void *` to an lvalue of type `int *`. It's assigning `void *` to an lvalue of type `void *` that's overlapping in storage with an object of type `int *`. This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Can a change done to void pointer be seen in pointer of type int

Comment: It might or might not be seen, or a random value might be seen, or your computer might explode, or monkeys might fly into your ass, because **you have invoked undefined behavior** if you make that assignment.

Comment: Also note that the code as written is not even valid C and should not be accepted by a compiler, because there is no implicit conversion from `int **` to `void **` in the C language. The compiler should give an error on this line: `mallocfn(&ptr, sizeof(ptr));`.

Comment: @R..: "It's assigning `void *` to an lvalue of type `void *` that's overlapping in storage with an object of type `int *`"  where does the overlap occur ? could you please elaborate?
I have updated the code with my accepting `int *`

Comment: You have a variable of type `void **` (pointer to `void *`) which is not actually pointing to a `void *` but to an `int *`. Thus, `*mem` is an lvalue of type `void *` that overlaps with `int *ptr;`. Not only is it possible for them to have different representations (this is mostly a stupid legacy consideration) but you have violated the aliasing rules, which can and will result in incorrect code generation, especially if the function gets inlined.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your example, a proper use of `malloc` would look more like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int *ptr = NULL;

   ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
   if (ptr != NULL)
   {
      *ptr = 3;

      free(ptr);         
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If you're learning C I suggest you get more self-motivated to read error messages and come to this conclusion yourself.  Let's parse them:

```
prog.c:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘malloc’
```

`malloc` is a standard function, and I guess `gcc` already knows how it's declared, treating it as a "built-in".  Typically when using standard library functions you want to `#include` the right header.  You can figure out which header based on documentation (`man malloc`).

In C++ you can declare functions that have the same name as already existing functions, with different parameters.  C will not let you do this, and so the compiler complains.

```
prog.c:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘malloc’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
prog.c:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘malloc’
```

Your `malloc` is calling itself.  You said that the first parameter was `void*` and that it had two parameters.  Now you are calling it with an integer.

```
prog.c:8: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

`NULL` is declared in standard headers, and you did not `#include` them.

```
prog.c:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘AllocateMemory’
```

You just called a function `AllocateMemory`, without telling the compiler what it's supposed to look like.  (Or providing an implementation, which will create a linker error.)

```
prog.c:12: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void
```

You said that main would return `int` (as it should), however you just said `return;` without a value.

Answer (score 1):

Abandon this whole idiom. There is no way to do it in C without making a separate allocation function for each type of object you might want to allocate. Instead use `malloc` the way it was intended to be used - with the pointer being returned to you in the return value. This way it automatically gets converted from `void *` to the right pointer type on assignment.

Comment: I was asked in an exam about this. So I am not sure about the possible issue with this code

Comment: What were you asked? Why it fails? The reason it fails is that you're just storing the return value of `malloc` in a function argument, which has automatic storage duration and ceases to exist when the function returns. The variable in the caller is never modified.